# NGINX 1.22.1 not correctly sending request round robin

Tags: nginx, debian, debian-bookworm

Debian: 12
Nginx: 1.22.1

**Goal**

Have Nginx route request to each server in a round robin fashion

**What is happening**

Nginx is only routing request to the first server no matter what

**What the expected behavior is**

I expect Nginx to route each request to the next server in the list. I can only guess that maybe there is a bug in nginx itself

**What have you tried**

I have rearranged all the servers in different orders in the list and they always just go to the first server. I have also tried to add the `least_conn` directive to the upstream and it had no effect.

Here is my configuration file *Note: I have replaced all instances of the url with X*

```yaml
upstream backend {
    least_conn;
    server x:443;
    server x:443;
    server x:443;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name x;
    
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/x/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/x/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://backend;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
        proxy_pass_request_body on;
        proxy_ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    }
}
```

Comment: Round robin is the default method and it's hard to believe it's broken. So it would be helpful to add some proofs. Such as nginx log with upstream_addr. Also it would be easier to understand if you hide different domains with different letters, not all x-es.